# Backbone: adding new model to a collection is not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm creating the very well known todo list app in backbone but there is one functionality that is not working, the `mycollection.add()` method.

Everything works fine when removing an item using `todoItems.remove(todoItem.at(0))`.
The problem I am having is when adding a new item:

`var newItem = new todoItem({ description: "cereal killer", status: "complete" });`

`todoItems.add(newItem)` --> This won't add it to the collection, the length is still the same.

The only way I can add a new item is to remove one first and then it will add the item but it will only work with one.

Any clue?

Here is the main code:

app.js

```
var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        description: "Pick up milk", 
        status: "incomplete", 
        id: 1
    },
    toggleStatus: function(){
        if(this.get('status') === 'incomplete'){
          this.set({'status': 'complete'});
        } else {
          this.set({'status': 'incomplete'});
        }
        this.save();
    } 
});

var TodoItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TodoItem,
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("choose-some-identifier"),

    initialize: function () {
        this.on('remove', this.hideModel, this);
    },

    hideModel: function (model) {
        model.trigger('hide');
    }
});

var TodosView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.addAll();
        // this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
        return this;
    },

    addOne: function (todoItem) {
        var todoView = new TodoView({ model: todoItem });
        this.$el.append(todoView.render().$el);
    },

    addAll: function () {
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);     
    }

});

var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'article',
    id: 'todo-view',
    className: 'todo',

    template: _.template('<h3 class="<%= status %>">' + 
        '<input type=checkbox ' + 
        '<% if (status === "complete") print("checked") %> />' + 
        '<%= description %></h3>'),

    events: {
        "change input": "toggleStatus"
    },

    toggleStatus: function () {
        this.model.toggleStatus();
    },

    remove: function(){
        this.$el.remove();
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
        this.model.on('hide', this.remove, this);
    },

    render: function () {
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
        return this;
    }
});

var todoItems = new TodoItems([
    {
        description: 'Jeffrey Way',
        status: "incomplete"
    },
    {
        description: 'John Doe',
        status: "incomplete"
    },
    {
        description: 'Sally Doe',
        status: "incomplete"
    }
]);

var todosView = new TodosView({ collection: todoItems});
$(document.body).append(todosView.render().el);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
defaults: {
    description: "Pick up milk", 
    status: "incomplete", 
    id: 1
}
```

You have set an `id` as a default. An id should be unique, you are trying to add another model without specifying a new id so Backone helpfully notices you already have a model with that id so it doesn't add it.

solution: You shouldn't be setting a default id, when creating models locally the normal process is:
- Create a model without an id
- At some point `.save` it
- Server responds with all the attributes + the id after saving

Of course fetching models that already existed on the server should already have an id.

PS you don't need to make a hash for a singular set (or get):

```
this.set('status', 'complete');
```

PPS In your view it is a good idea to use `listenTo`:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', ...);
```

This protects from memleaks in some instances and makes it easier to batch stop listening to events.

Comment: Thank you so much. This have helped and also the advices you gave to me. Really appreciate.